# TSQL Concatenation

Tags: t-sql, concatenation

### I often need to concatenate fields in TSQL...

Two issues TSQL forces you to deal with when using the '+' operator are [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and NULL values.

With Data Type Precedence, the problem is conversion errors.

```
1) SELECT 1 + 'B' = Conversion ERROR
2) SELECT 1 + '1' = 2
3) SELECT '1' + '1' = '11'
```

In 2), the varchar '1' is implicitly converted to an int, and the math works.  However, in 1), the int 1 is NOT implicitly converted to a varchar.  This is where DTP is (IMO) getting in the way.  Essentially, it favors Math functions over String functions.  *I Wish* :-) that DTP wasn't even a consideration in this case -- why wouldn't the '+' operator be configured so that the operation could favor *success* over specific data-types?  I wouldn't mind if it still favored MATH over String functions when possible -- but why doesn't it favor String functions over Errors?  (The only way to be successful in 1) is to treat it as a string function -- so it's not like there's any ambiguity there.)  Somebody at Microsoft thought that throwing an error in 1) would be more valuable to the programmer than treating the '+' as a string function.  Why?  And why didn't they provide a way to override it? (Or did they...that's really the heart of my question.)  `SET STRING_PREFERENCE ON` would have been nice!  :-P

In order to deal with this, you have to do more work -- you have to explicitly convert the 1 to a varchar, using any number of different string functions -- typically CAST/CONVERT, but also many others (like LTRIM()) will work.

Conversions become work-intensive when you deal with table fields when you don't know the data-type. This might work:

```
SELECT 'Fall '  + ' (' + [Term] + ')' -- Output: Fall (2011)
```

But then again, it might not.  It just depends on what data-type of [Term] is.  And to complicate that, the dba might change the dataype at some point without telling anyone (because it came as part of a big upgrade package once the vendor finally realized that there are only ever numbers stored in the [Term] field, or whatever reason).

So if you want to be a boyscount, you do this:

```
SELECT 'Fall '  + ' (' + LTRIM([Term]) + ')'
```

So now I'm running this LTRIM function every time, even though it *might* not be necessary, because I don't know the data-type of [Term] (OK -- I can look that up, but that's almost like work, and I don't like interruptions while I'm coding :-P **grump*), and also, I don't know that the data-type will never change.

The second issue you have to confront with TSQL concatenation is how to deal with NULL values. For example, this would fail:

```
SELECT NULL + 'B'
```

So you need to do this:

```
SELECT 'Fall '  + ' (' + LTRIM(ISNULL([Term],'')) + ')'
```

What a pain -- I wish I could just do this:

```
SELECT 'Fall '  + ' (' + [Term] + ')'
```

So I'm wondering if there are any (TSQL) ways to avoid having to do explicit data-type conversions and null checks on every field where I have to ensure the '+' operator behaves itself as I need it to.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
@a1ex07 came up with a great answer for working around the NULL issue (`SET CONCAT_NULL_YEILDS_NULL OFF`), but as I looked into it, it appears to be problematic as far as forcing stored procedures to re-compile every time they're executed.

Comment: It's called data type precedence.  You should probably read up on it.

Comment: Thanks @JNK -- I understand why it's happening  -- just hoping to find a more convenient method for removing that (DTP) roadblock when I need to.  Anyway, I should have mentioned it, so I'll edit the question.

Comment: I might be missing something here but I just don't see how this will fail other than with null values. `select [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]`. Null values is taken care of by `isnull`. Test here. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110365/

Comment: @Mikael -- it also fails if [FirstName] = 1

Comment: Yes -- I understand about using isnull() -- my hope (or just my whining) is that there's got to be a better (less work-intensive) way.

Comment: @Mikael -- just tried that data explorer -- cool idea.  I see what you mean about the integer concat then.  But unfortunately, SQL-Server doesn't behave the same way -- concat an int with a varchar, and you'll get a Conversion Failed error.

Comment: That is SQL Server 2008. If you have an int field you of course have to cast it first. You do not need to cast a varchar field that contains an int. Or rather the character 1.

Comment: Agree with Mikael a `1` stored in a `varchar` column won't cause any issues as you suggest.

Comment: @Mikael -- OK -- Thank you, you're right.  I had a different case in mind when I included that, but was trying to use a simpler / analogous case in the post, so I made up an incorrect example.  Fixed it / modified the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no answer to this for 2005 or 2008.  Concatenation without explicit conversions and null checks simply isn't possible.

It looks like the next version of SQL-Server will have a CONCAT function (thanks @Martin) which sounds like *exactly* what I'm looking for.  The downside though is that it will probably be at least a handful of years before my institution decides to upgrade to that version, since they're pretty shy about being early adopters, especially when it comes to Microsoft.

There is a shortcut for the NULL checks right now (CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL -- thanks @a1ex07), however, using that has a pretty big penalty (re-compiles the procedure every time it is executed), not to mention Microsoft isn't planning to support it in future versions of SQL-Server.

Comment: What about `COALESCE` for handling null values?  As in: `SELECT COALESCE(@A,'') + 1`

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server 2012 does have the [`CONCAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) function which addresses all the issues you raise.

A good summary of the functionality is provided [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/concat-function-in-sql-server) by [SQL Menace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740/sqlmenace)

> CONCAT takes a variable number of string arguments and concatenates
>   them into a single string. It requires a minimum of two input values;
>   otherwise, an error is raised. All arguments are implicitly converted
>   to string types and then concatenated. Null values are implicitly
>   converted to an empty string. If all the arguments are null, then an
>   empty string of type varchar(1) is returned. The implicit conversion
>   to strings follows the existing rules for data type conversions

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
You can use [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) to specify whether `NULL + 'txt'` results `NULL`. 
Microsft says that `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will not work in further versions of SQL Server, but there is still an option to set it through  [sp_dboption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187310.aspx) procedure . But probably it's better to use `ISNULL` as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JNK: Sorry for very laconic first answer, I just tried to post it first :)

Comment: @a1ex07 - at least you fixed it.  No worries.

Comment: ...that sounded really good for a minute there -- I'm reading up on it, and I guess this causes re-compiling in stored precdures (which is where I'd be doing it) and they recommend using isnull() instead...so that's too bad...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/*  1 */ SELECT cast(1 as varchar) + 'B'; /* = 1B */
/* or */ SELECT convert(varchar, 1) + 'B'; /* = 1B */

/*  2 */ SELECT cast(1 as varchar) + '1'; /* = 11 */

/*  3 */ SELECT '1' + '1'; /* = 11 */
/* or */ SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, '1') + CONVERT(VARCHAR, '1');

--NULL value:
DECLARE @A AS VARCHAR(10);
SET @A = NULL;
SELECT ISNULL(@A, '') + 1; /* = 1 */
```